# Trying to find the time difference (in minutes) from a given time and the current time now in my React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, time, date-difference

I'm building a London bus live departures application but struggling to display the amount of time in minutes until the next bus arrives. Currently I'm able to display the time that the bus will arrive but want to display this such so that it reads "2 mins" etc. instead of just the time of its arrival.

The value within the transportAPI that I'm working with is displayed as a string such as "14:49" for example and is called: expected_departure_estimate

It seems simple in just taking this given time and finding the difference between the current time and that but I keep struggling and receive NaN in the UI.

Here's my code:

```
    const BusInfo = ({ busStopInfo }) => {
  const [busList, setBusList] = useState({});
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getBusTimes = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await axios(`${url}/${busStopInfo.atcocode}/live.json`, {
          params: {
            app_id: apiId,
            app_key: apiKey,
            group: "no",
            limit: 10,
            nextbuses: "yes",
          },
        });

        setBusList(result.data.departures);
        console.log(result.data.departures);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
    };

    getBusTimes();
  }, [busStopInfo.atcocode]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h5>{busStopInfo.name}</h5>
      <p>{busStopInfo.description}</p>
      {busList.all &&
        busList.all.map((departure, i) => (
          <li style={{ listStyleType: "none" }} key={i}>
            <h6>
              <span className={styles.busItem}>{departure.line}</span> <small>towards</small>{" "}
              {departure.direction} {departure.best_departure_estimate}
            </h6>
          </li>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BusInfo;
```

[image: console.log of data from API]

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need something like that

```
function howLongTill(timeString) {
  let current = new Date();
  let today = current.getHours()*60 + current.getMinutes()
  let bus = timeString.split(":")
  let h = parseFloat(bus[0]);
  let m = parseFloat(bus[1]);

  let n = h*60 + m - today
  return n > 0 ? n + " min." : "gone"
}
```

but you need to fix the issue if the bus-coming-time will be from the next day, by your own :)